# Pivot data table in flutter

Tags: flutter, pivot

I am trying to move an existing angular page into flutter. I have a third party pivot grid to display tabular data and don't find anything similar in/for flutter.

Is there a way to create a widget and display flutter's **datatable** into pivot format?

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the DataTable widget as you like using the `DataColumn`, `DataRow` and the `DataCell` classes inside the DataTable widget

You can read in detail [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html)

Comment: these are flat grid, am looking for a 3 dimensional like the below -  https://docs.devart.com/images/studio-for-sql-server/pg_create_table.png

Comment: You should edit your question accordingly 
It creates ambiguity for someone who wants to answer